# Grep through the results of a 'find' command

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do a simple search through files.

1. Find all files that match a name pattern
2. Grep through results of step 1 and find only files whose contents have a specific string

I tried,

```
find . -name rio.yml -exec  grep "my pattern" \;
```

Whats best practice for something like this.

Comment: What output do you want? File paths for files containing your string, or the matching lines?

Comment: `find . -name rio.yml -exec grep -H "my pattern" {} \;`

Comment: or, if `grep` doesn't support -H, `grep "my pattern" /dev/null {} \;`

Comment: `grep -l CONTENTPATTERN FILENAMEPATTERN` should be sufficient if files are in current directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the filename which contains some string, you need to use `grep -l`

```
find . -name rio.yml -exec  grep -l "my pattern" {} \;
```

To get full path of the files; you can use `$(pwd)` in place of search directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the paths that contain the match, do:

```
find . -name rio.yml -type f -exec grep -q "my pattern" {} \; -print
```

(Given that you're already filtering on the name, the `-type f` may be redundant, but I find it helpful when grepping.)  You can use `grep -l`, but it's often convenient to build a pipeline to xargs with `-print0`, so this is a good pattern.